# Should I use &nbsp; or padding to separate horizontal list items

Tags: html, css

I want to put some space between some horizontally laid out list items, should I use `&nbsp;` or padding-left to separate them?

`&nbsp` example:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu_item">Option 1&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="menu_item">Option 2</li>
</ul>
```

padding-left example:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu_item">Option 1</li>
    <li class="menu_item">Option 2</li>
</ul>
.menu li.menu_item { padding-left: 10px; }
```

Comment: `padding` should be used or `margin`, but as you compared with `&nbsp;` than you can use `padding`

Comment: Never use html to style, always css, so padding it is (or margin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer.  Use `padding-left` it's easier to maintain, change and it's more customizable. As suggested above you might even want to use `margin` instead of `padding` this is usually necessary to separate items with a `background-color`.

I'll show an example just give me a second to make one.

### Edit:

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6mgL/2/show/). I decided to just show you full screen since you already know the html and css.

Notice how the background-color is seperated with margins, but not with padding or &nbsp.  Margin is often useful for that reason, but sometimes you want the background color in the spacing.  You can use both `margin` and `padding` to get the spacing you want.

The reason why margin works that way and padding doesn't is because of the box-model.  More about the box-model [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model).

Answer (score 1):

Padding is definitly the best way to do that. 
In fact it will be more easy for you later, to customize your list...
Imagine that there is not only 2-3 colums or row in your list but 100 etc...
Take a list like this:

```
  <ul class="menu">  
    <li> Option 1 </li>
    <li> Option 2 </li>
  </ul>
```

The css part would looks like this:

```
  .menu
   { 
     //Your style..
   }
   .menu li
   {
      padding-left: 5px; //As you wants...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refrain from using `&nbsp;`

`padding-left` is the right option.

Alternatively you can use `margin-left`

As you are creating a menu, I would suggest (based on my past experience) using `margin-left` for list being used for menu items. Gives more flexibility and cleanliness.